# Input signal out of range while installing Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: ubuntu

I've started the Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation on my Dell R210 II, but right after displaying a few pages of text the monitor goes black, then displays the message `input signal out of range`.
I've worked around this by editing and adding `nomodeset` in GRUB at the end of the linux line.
Now the installer goes further, but shows this error and would not continue `ubuntu server probing for devices to install to failed`
Here I've got stuck and could not find anything relevant to go further (or at least for my level on knowledge :-))

I've decided to install Ubuntu Server `20.04`, then upgrade to `22.04` later, thinking I might bypass the probing error this way.
The Ubuntu Server `20.04` installation went fine without issues, then I have upgraded to `22.04`, but after the restart I get again the `input signal out of range` message on my monitor.

I think something goes wrong because I can't ssh into the system, so clearly it does not fully boot.

I would appreciate your help to make 22.04 work on my server, if possible.
Is there a way to make a change in how Ubuntu starts and add something like `nomodeset` as I dit before for the installer?

I have the upgraded `22.04` on one drive and another `20.04` on another if this helps.
I don't have any other hardware beside the Dell R210 II motherboard with the on board GPU

Comment: Are you using the onboard Matrox G200eW video card, or do you have an add on video card?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231887/20-04-lts-boot-hang-matrox-g200ew-after-successful-install

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm using the onboard Matrox G200eW and it seems to be a driver issue. I will try the recommendations from the link you have shared.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work using the low resolution with @user10489 suggestion from https://askubuntu.com/a/1241370/498148

1. start Ubuntu once with the `nomodeset` parameter
   in GRUB edit the first option and add `nomodeset` at the end of the `linux` line
2. persist the `nomodeset` parameter
   once Ubuntu started, edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value add `nomodeset` like

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
> ```

more details here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Answer (score 1):

The "**signal input is out of range**" issue is easily resolved. The problem is twofold. This occurs during installation and upgrade.

So from Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04, the resolution setting was moved from the start-up manager to the kernel. Before, it was solved using **Startup-Manager**, but since “Startup-Manager is dead,” it was dropped from Ubuntu 12.04’s repository.

Start your boot device during installation, press F6 only select *ACPI* and *nomodeset* and continue with installation in **safe graphics**.

In **Simple steps**

```
sudo nano/etc/default/grub
```

find the line;

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Remove the # and change 640x480 to the preferred mode you have with your monitor. e.g 1024x768, 1280x1024, and 1600x900.

Then find grub **command line setting**;

Add **nomodeset** to the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** value as shown below.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Save, then type

```
sudo update-grub
```

You need also to update your OS after updating grub

```
sudo apt update
```

You can also **follow all** of the [steps here](https://viralate.com/2023/02/01/solved-monitor-input-signal-out-of-range/), which saved me months of searching online for my old desktop computer.